# Smear vs smudge

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Here what will be a natural  way to describe this:

> You have smudged  your mascara by crying.
>
> You have smeared your mascara by crying.

And what if it was done on purpose, what will  be ised in that case?  (Hand was used)  And what if someone tries to wipe off the tears and smudges it?

[image]

And what about glasses :

> You have smeared  the lenses.
>
> Yoy have smudged the lenses.

(They are blurry  now)

Answer (score 2):

For many purposes, "smear": and "smudge" have pretty much the same meaning.  When it is done intentionally with makeup, I would use "smudge". When is is done intentionally by a a painter using oil pain, I would use "smear".  When refering to a situation like that in the image, I would use "run" rather than either "smear" or "smudge:

> Your tears have caused your mascara to run.

For glasses I would prefer "smudge", but I have heard "smear" used. Both "smear" and "smudge" suggest a wiping motion to me, rather than the running of a dissolved or suspended substance.

Comment: And when  it doesn't  run, as in the image, like it just spreads, what will be a natural way to describe that?

Comment: @It's that could certainly be described as a "smear", or possibly as a "smudge". or the makeup could be said to be "messed-up".

Comment: And what will be a natural way to describe  the "unintended action with hands"?